# Notify service defined in included LWRP recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is there a way to notify a service to restart which is defined by an included LWRP?

I wrote an LWRP called "sidekiq" which sets up a service, like this, and appears to be working fine on its own.

```
service "#{new_resource.name}_sidekiq" do
  provider Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
  action [ :enable ]
  subscribes :restart, "template[/etc/init/#{new_resource.name}_sidekiq.conf]", :immediately
end
```

The problem is I am using it another recipe which I use for deployments, and need it to notify the service defined in the LWRP. I currently have something this

```
include_recipe "sidekiq"
deploy_revision my_dir do
  notifies :restart, "service[myapp_sidekiq]"
end
```

The problem is at compile time, chef looks at this recipe and gives an error

> ERROR: resource deploy_revision[my_dir] is configured to notify resource service[myapp_sidekiq] with action restart, but service[myapp_sidekiq] cannot be found in the resource collection.

I can get rid of the error by defining an empty service in my deployment recipe, like `service 'myapp_sidekiq'`, and everything will work fine when first provisioning the machine.  However if I run a deployment and nothing changes in the sidekiq LWRP, the myapp_sidekiq service is never redefined and thus cannot be restarted.

Comment: If nothing has changed, why does the service has to be redefined ?

Comment: The service doesn't need to be redefined.  I just need to notify it to restart.

Comment: So just create a service resource in your recipe with action nothing as @mtm expose in his answer, you'll have resource of type service with can be notified and your lwrp still takes care of enabling it with the resource inside the lwrp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [notify](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html#notifications) a resource to complete an action, that resource must be defined previously in the current Chef run, and as Tensibai notes not defined `inline` in it's own `run_context`

#### Place holder

The simple way is to create a place holder in your deploy script of your non default provider that has an action of `:nothing`, but you can notify it later.

```
service "myapp_sidekiq deploy notifier" do
  provider      Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
  service_name  "myapp_sidekiq"
  action        :nothing
end
```

You can also modify the overall default provider for a resource in `client.rb` if you are using Upstart all the time on a platform that Chef has configured as something else, like `systemd`

```
Chef::Platform.set :platform => :yours, :resource => :service, :provider => Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
```

There are [changes coming in Chef 12](https://github.com/opscode/chef/pull/1596) that will let Chef evaluate which service provider to use at run time instead of static configuration. This is basically due to systemd coming along and shaking up something on systems that was once very stable and predicatable.

Be careful of the `name` you use for resources. If you have multiple `service` resources defined via the same service name you can run into issues due to they way [Chef treats them as clones](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3694) and you may be running something you didn't expect. If you are using multiple service definitions try naming them something unique for the specific purpose. Then in the attributes, specify the service with `service_name`

#### LWRP

If you had a particularly complex resource that you are defining repeatedly and you think you should only be specifying all the generic parameters for it once, you could create your own [Light Weight Resource and Provider](http://docs.getchef.com/lwrp_custom_provider.html) encapsulating all the generic setup so you can define the resource more easily in recipes:

```
service_myapp_sidekiq "deploy notifier" do
  action      :nothing
end

service_myapp_sidekiq "config subscriber" do
  action      :nothing
  subscribes  :restart, 'blah'
end
```

That is a lot of work as you have to create an LWRP `action` for every underlying action you want to support and as you can see, doesn't make your use case much easier.

#### Library function

You could also do the same sort of thing with a function in a [library](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbook_libraries.html) that defines the basics of the resource and allows you to add any of the customisations you want (like name).

```
def create_myapp_service name, action, options = {}
  s = Chef::Resource::Service.new "myapp service #{name}"
  s. service_name   "myapp_sidekiq"
  s.provider        Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
  s.action          action
end

create_myapp_service "deploy", :nothing
```

Again, these are probably only needed for much more complex resource setups and cases where you repeatedly need to define the same complex resource with small variations.

**TLDR**: Define a place holder `service` which does `:nothing` for the deploy.

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed answer, but the placeholder method doesn't seem to work for me.  To make sure I'm understanding correctly.. I left my sidekiq LWRP the way it is.  In the recipe that does the deployment I added `deploy_revision my_app
  notifies :restart, "service[myapp_sidekiq deploy notifier]"
end`

Comment: It does work if I specify the provider `provider    Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart` in the placeholder. Is this necessary?  It works fine but now my deployment recipe is dependent on the way that the sidekiq recipe manages the service.

Comment: What os/version are you on?

Comment: Added some details about the default service provider in Chef as I'm guessing your on a distro that you have added systemd to or has recently moved to systemd.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.  In this case I specifically do not want to use the default service provider, as the sidekiq recipe used Upstart to demonize a program.  I was hoping that I could notify the service defined in the other recipe and control the service provider there, but I guess its not possible.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

LWRP with `use_inline_resources` use their own `run_context`, so resources inside a LWRP are not included in the `resource_collection` and are not able to be notified outside the LWRP.

LWRP without the inline resources flag add their inner resources to the resource collection, but at converge phase et not at compile, so you'll still have the error you see.

> However if I run a deployment and nothing changes in the sidekiq LWRP,
>   the myapp_sidekiq service is never redefined and thus cannot be
>   restarted.

I really don't understand what you mean, unless your deploy_revision should change the enable/disbale state of the service or what it supports (status, restart, reload, etc.), there's no need to re-enable it, just define a service resource for deploy_revision to notify it to restart.