# chef notify global service from inside of LWRP provider code

Tags: chef-infra

I see that if `service['somename']` gets created inside LWRP with `use_inline_resources` enabled, then this resource is not visible in other contexts - as explained here: [Notify service defined in included LWRP recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792383/notify-service-defined-in-included-lwrp-recipe)

I have situation where `service['somename']` is defined in normal recipe (not in LWRP provider). Then LWRP provider is trying to notify this service. In my example service is web server and LWRP is responsible for creating virtual hosts inside this web server.

If I use `use_inline_resources` in that provider, code inside provider do not see resources defined in global scope (in normal recipes). Cookbook with recipe defining this service is added as `depends cookbookname` in `metadata.rb`.

So the question is: how is actually working `use_inline_resources` - official explanation is not clear to me (http://docs.getchef.com/lwrp_common_inline_compile.html). This explanation says the opposite I see - it says:

> To ensure that an embedded lightweight resource can notify the
>   top-level resource add `use_inline_resources` to the top of the file

In my situation I have recipe:

> include_recipe "web-server::install" # creates service['web-server']
>
> this_cookbook_my_lwrp "sites" do     # this LWRP is trying to notify service['web-server']
>   action :create
>   end

So this LWRP is defined in this cookbook. And it behaves like this:

- if LWRP contains `use_inline_resources`, it cannot see service['web-server']
- if LWRP not contains `use_inline_resources`, it can see service['web-server']

Besides, does defining `use_inline_resources` has any influence on anything other that resources visibility?

Answer (score 2):

If you looking for way to notify global service from inside of lrwp you can use following code inside of provider action:

```
webserver = run_context.parent_run_context.resource_collection.find('service[webserver]')
new_resource.notifies :restart, webserver
```

Answer (score 1):

> To ensure that an embedded lightweight resource can notify the top-level resource add use_inline_resources to the top of the file

What this is saying is that adding `use_inline_resources` to your LWRP will cause the LWRP resource to be marked as `updated` if ANY of the embedded resources is `updated`.  This allows you to treat the the LWRP resource as a single unit, rather than a collection of other resources (which is what a definition is).

If you have resource external to the LWRP that need to subscribe to an embedded resource, you probably have a design issue in regards to your LWRP (it is either trying to do too much, or trying to do too little).  If your external resource can, it should subscribe to the LWRP itself, rather than the embedded resource.

Likewise, if your LWRP needs to access an external resource to notify it, then your LWRP is not self-contained.  I assume your LWRP needs to notify the service resource for your webserver to reload after adding the vhost?  If that's the case then you're asking your LWRP to do something it shouldn't do.  Your LWRP is responsible for configuring a VHOST, but it is not responsible for starting/reloading the webserver.  Likewise, the mechanism you use to install the webserver is not responsible for starting it.  You declare a `service` resource to start your webserver with, and that `service` resource is also responsible for subscribing to any resource that might require a reload to happen (or those resources - like instances of your LWRP - should be notifying the webserver).

```
mycool_vhost 'some vhost' do
  attribute value
  other_attribute value
end

service 'mywebserver' do
  subscribes :reload, "mycool_vhost[some vhost]"
end
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The main effect of `use_inline_resources` is to create a new context of execution for the LWRP.

It makes all resources inside the LWRP in their own run context.

You may see it as a chef run inside the chef run.

The idea is to be able to makes things inside the LWRP and abstracting them totally, the LWRP resource will takes the update status from its inner resources, so a notification in the LWRP declaration (recipe side) would be through is something has changed inside the LWRP.

Using `use_inline_resources`, the resources inside the LWRP can notify each others. 
Without use_inline_resources, they'll be added to the main `run_context` and `resource_collection` at the converge pahse and not at compile time, and it will usually ends up with internal notifications not working and sometimes resources duplication if the LWRP define a service or resources with fixed name.

Hope it makes it a little more clear.